# How do I convert a word to phonetic alphabet in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying write a code to convert a word into phonetic alphabet. The desired return value should be something like this:

```
# >> Type your name and I will convert it to Phonetic Alphabets!
Kevin
# >> Kilo Echo Victor India November
```

I wrote a hash.

```
puts "Type your name and I will convert it to Phonetic Alphabets!"
name = gets.chomp
nato_keys =  {
    "A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo",   "C": "Charlie",
    "D": "Delta",  "E": "Echo",    "F": "Foxtrot",
    "G": "Golf",   "H": "Hotel",   "I": "India",
    "J": "Juliett","K": "Kilo",    "L": "Lima",
    "M": "Mike",   "N": "November","O": "Oscar",
    "P": "Papa",   "Q": "Quebec",  "R": "Romeo",
    "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango",   "U": "Uniform",
    "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray",
    "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"
  }

def nato()
    puts name.nato_keys.upcase().join(" ")
end
```

I have an issue with my method as it triggers an error.

Comment: `name.chars.map{ |x| nato_keys[x.upcase.to_sym] }.join(' ')`

Comment: Please edit to show your desired return value for the string used in your example (`"Type your name,..."`).

Comment: @kiddorails this is neat! I hadn't thought of the .to_sym . I appreciate it. Did the job.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks - I edited to show the desired outcome.

Comment: @AlfatahKader great added it as answer.

Comment: You can add `.with_indifferent_access` to the end of your `nato_keys` definition, which will allow you to use either strings or symbols, whichever is more convenient.

Comment: @moveson `.with_indifferent_access` will only work with ActiveSupport. Good idea for a Rails app!

Comment: "I have an issue" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do this:

```
name.chars.map { |x| nato_keys[x.upcase.to_sym] }.join(' ')
```

This `name.chars` give the enumeration with each character of the string `name`, `map` iterates on each character and transforms it to the instruction in the block.

block `{ |x| nato_keys[x.upcase.to_sym] }`, picks the relevant mapping for the character, but before that, it converts the key to uppercase and symbol(because in your `nato_keys`, keys are symbols). 'a' will become `:A`.

After the block manipulation, we join the result with ' ' to give resultant string.

Answer (score 4):

Since no one mentioned it, here's a solution with `values_at` (this assumes string keys in the substitutions hash, as they should be).

```
str = "Kevin"
nato_keys.values_at(*str.upcase.chars).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the number of words to converted is more than 26 it makes sense to prepare the appropriate hash before doing any conversions.

```
H = nato_keys.transform_keys(&:to_s)
  #=> {"A"=>"Alpha", "B"=>"Bravo",..., "Z"=>"Zulu"}

word = gets.chomp
```

Supose

```
word = "Kevin"
```

Then

```
word.upcase.each_char.map { |c| H[c] }.join(' ')
  #=> "Kilo Echo Victor India November"
```

Comment: I thought the " " quotes rendered everything in the nato_keys into string, no?

Comment: @Sergio, what are you talking about? I never said that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: indeed, my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

`name.upcase.chars.map(&:intern).map(&nato_keys).join(' ')`

First we `upcase` the entire string.  We then split the string into each individual char and turn each into a symbol.  Then we can map over the chars sending them one at a time to the `nato_keys` element reference `[]`, returning the phonetic word, and converting the name. Finally, join them with spaces to format the new string.

EDIT: When using Hash element references we can call the Hash itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Cary Swoveland says, the hash `nato_keys`, which really does not make sense, has to be converted to one that makes sense:

```
nato_keys.transform_keys!(&:to_s)
```

Given:

```
name = "Kevin"
```

then,

```
name.gsub(/(\A)?./){"#{" " unless $1}#{nato_keys[$&.upcase]}"}
# => "Kilo Echo Victor India November"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would start with preparing more robust hash to transform

```
transform =
  nato_keys.
  flat_map do |k, v|
    v = v + ' '
    [[k.to_s, v], [k.to_s.downcase, v]]
  end.
  to_h.
  tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(h, k) { h[k] = k } }
```

Now you might transform your words as easy as:

```
"Kevin".gsub(/./, transform).strip
#⇒ "Kilo Echo Victor India November"
```